# What are the differences between object and spring beans?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

You may explain the differences between spring bean and object.

I also still don't understand beans in spring What exactly is the role of spring beans in spring?

Apparently, the definition that beans form the main backbone of our application is not enough.

Comment: A bean is an class instance (an object) managed by spring. All Spring beans are objects, not all objects are spring beans.

Comment: refer to https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html , once you understand IOC , "Beans are Objects managed by IOC" will make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java development, a Spring Bean and a Java Object are related concepts and they have somewhat different purposes. The biggest difference is, that Spring Beans can only be used in the context of the Spring Framework.

- Java Object: In the Java programming language, an object is an instance of a class. It represents a specific entity with its own set of properties (variables) and behaviors (methods).
- Spring Bean: In the context of Spring, a bean is an object that is managed by the Spring IoC (Inversion of Control) container. The Spring framework is responsible for creating, initializing, and managing the lifecycle of beans. Beans are typically Java objects that are configured and managed by Spring.

Spring as Framework offers some functions, such as:

- Lifecycle management: Spring Beans are managed by the Spring container, which handles their creation, initialization, and destruction. Java Objects, on the other hand, are typically created and managed by the programmer manually.
- Dependency injection: Spring Beans can benefit from dependency injection, which allows them to receive dependencies from the Spring container. This enables loose coupling and easier testing. Java Objects, on the other hand, do not have built-in support for dependency injection.
- Configuration: Spring Beans are often defined and configured in XML or Java-based configuration files (what I do most), specifying their properties, dependencies, and other settings. Java Objects are typically instantiated and configured directly in Java-code.